# Shutting down an Akka Actor system from an Actor

Tags: scala, akka

I know I can use `system.shutdown()` outside of an actor system to stop the actor system and make `system.awaitTermination()` stop blocking execution on its thread.

I want to trigger the actor system shutdown from within one of my Actors.  I thought I should be able to call `context.system.shutdown()` from within an Actor's receive method, however when I do this nothing seems to happen, `system.awaitTermination()` (on the main thread) just keeps on blocking.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

How to program an Actor to kill self

```
class WatchActor extends Actor {

   val child = context.actorOf(Props.empty, "child")
   context.watch(child) // <-- this is the only call needed for registration
   var lastSender = system.deadLetters

def receive = {
  case "kill" =>
   context.stop(child); lastSender = sender()
   case Terminated(`child`) => lastSender ! "finished"
  }
}
```

At this url there is a good explain.

http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/actors.html

jfm

Comment: Please don't only post link answers. Just put the essential parts of the link in your answer

Answer (score 0):

You should not do that: **it is like a snake biting its own tail**.

`system.awaitTermination()` will keep blocking because you are precisely waiting for it to end!

You can perfectly call `context.system.shutdown()` within an actor, but you cannot call `system.awaitTermination()` in the actor system context. And also it does not make a lot of sense: why would you wait since there is anyway nothing to execute afterwards, the system being down?

Blocking on the system to shut down makes sense outside of it only, if you want to execute further instructions after it has been stopped.

Comment: I am not calling `system.awaitTermination()` from inside an actor.  That call is on the main thread, the same thread that was responsible for starting the actor system.  My problem is that when I call `context.system.shutdown ()` from within an actor, the system does not shutdown, and the main thread, which is blocking waiting for shutdown, just keeps on blocking.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake for reading too fast. Are you sure nothing else is being executed in your system?

Answer (score 0):

Main Thread:

```
val l = new CountDownLatch(1)
val s = ActorSystem("system", config)
...
//create some actors and send some messages to them
...
l.await()
s.shutdown()
s.awaitTermination()
```

Some where in `def receive: Actor.Receive`:

```
l.countDown()
```